# Find number of nodes in left and right subtree of a complete binary tree if total number of nodes are given in O(1)

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to find count of nodes in left and right subtree of complete binary tree if total nodes are given,

for example,

n = 5
===> left -> 3 right -> 1

n = 8
===> left -> 4 right -> 3

where n is total number of nodes in a binary tree

is there any formula or O(1)/optimal solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any formula or O(1)/optimal solution to do this?

Yes.

Write the given  (number of nodes) in binary notation, and turn every 1 to a 0, except the most significant 1. Call this number . Define  as  − , so that in binary it is the same as , but with its most significant digit removed. The number of nodes in the *right* subtree wil be equal to max(,  / 2 − 1).

It is then a piece of cake to know how many are in the *left* subtree, because the sum of nodes in both subtrees plus 1 (for the root node) must be equal to .

### Your example

When  = 5, we note that down in binary as 0b101. We can see that  = 0b100 and  = 0b001. So the right subtree has max(, /2 − 1) nodes, i.e. max(1, 1) = 1. The left subtree has the remaining nodes, i.e. 3, so that 3 + 1 + 1 (for root) = 5.

### Other examples

Here is a table with the results for  between 1 and 15:

|  | in binary |  |  | /2 − 1 | in right subtree = max(, /2 − 1) | in left subtree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0b1 | 0b1 | 0b0 | 0b0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0b10 | 0b10 | 0b0 | 0b0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0b11 | 0b10 | 0b1 | 0b1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0b100 | 0b100 | 0b00 | 0b1 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 0b101 | 0b100 | 0b01 | 0b1 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0b110 | 0b100 | 0b10 | 0b1 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 0b111 | 0b100 | 0b11 | 0b1 | 3 | 3 |
| 8 | 0b1000 | 0b1000 | 0b000 | 0b11 | 3 | 4 |
| 9 | 0b1001 | 0b1000 | 0b001 | 0b11 | 3 | 5 |
| 10 | 0b1010 | 0b1000 | 0b010 | 0b11 | 3 | 6 |
| 11 | 0b1011 | 0b1000 | 0b011 | 0b11 | 3 | 7 |
| 12 | 0b1100 | 0b1000 | 0b100 | 0b11 | 4 | 7 |
| 13 | 0b1101 | 0b1000 | 0b101 | 0b11 | 5 | 7 |
| 14 | 0b1110 | 0b1000 | 0b110 | 0b11 | 6 | 7 |
| 15 | 0b1111 | 0b1000 | 0b111 | 0b11 | 7 | 7 |